# I can not get data from the database due to the dynamic value provided

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Website on wordpress. To print a booked PDF ticket, I use plugins: woocommerce and woocommerce-pdf-invoices-packing-slips. Before printing, in the letter template, I need to add some data from the database table. The plugin has a variable `$this->order_id` - it contains the order number.

I tried to make such a query to the database:

```
global $wpdb;
$wt_order_ids = $wpdb->query($wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->prefix}my_table WHERE order_id = %d", $this->order_id));
```

As a result, nothing is displayed. But, if the request is edited a little:

```
$wt_order_ids = $wpdb->query($wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->prefix}my_table WHERE order_id = 777"));
```

those. instead of $this->order_id, register an order number already in the table, for example 777, then the request works as expected, and I get the data I need.

I thought maybe at the moment when I try to access the database, the actual order number is not yet in the database. Then why can I print $this->order_id using echo or print_r, but cannot use it when accessing the database?

Please help me solve this problem. I really need to use $this->order_id

Answer (score 0):

You can make query string completely and then pass it to `$wpdb->query()` such as following code:

```
global $wpdb;
$query = "SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->prefix}my_table WHERE order_id = {$this->order_id}";
$wt_order_ids = $wpdb->get_results($query);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn’t help. Are there any other options?

Comment: You must to print `$query` variable to we see what is this variable.

Comment: This is what the variable contains:
`SELECT * FROM wp_my_table WHERE order_id = 874`

Comment: @VladSiy There is an order with 874 order_id? check your database and say to me what do you see.

Comment: Yes, there is an order 874

Comment: $wpdb->query($query); equals 0

Comment: @VladSiy you use `$wpdb->get_results` instead of `$wpdb->query`

Comment: `$query = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->prefix}wbtm_bus_booking_list WHERE order_id = {$this->order_id}");` - To no avail.